# I'm trying to write a python script that changes the dictionary address names and cities by their id and save it to a new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I coded a loop but I have an empty dictionary and I'm also looking to save it to a new file

```
f = open('files/person')
g = open('files/city')
h = open('files/address')
ch1 = f.readline()
ch2 = g.readline()
ch3 = h.readline()
dico_person = {}
dico_address = {}
dico_city = {}
dico_addressFinally = {}

# Person:
for j in ch1:
    id_name = ch1[:1]
    name_person = ch1 [2:12]
    ch1 = f.readline()
    dico_person[id_name] = {'name person': [name_person]}
print(dico_person)
# City:
for k in ch2:
    city = ch2[:11]
    id_city = ch2[12:14]
    ch2 = g.readline()
    dico_city[id_city] = {'city': [city]}
#print(dico_city)

for i in ch3:
    name_address = ch3[:11]
    city_address = ch3[12:24]
    ch3 = h.readline()
    dico_address[name_address] = {'city address': [city_address]}
print(dico_address)

for k in dico_address:
    for v in dico_person:
        if name_address == name_person:
            name_address = id_name
        dico_addressFinally[name_address] = {'city address': [city_address]}
print(dico_addressFinally)
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details and use the triple backticks -> ``` to format your code correctly

Comment: @RMPR I tried to submit an edit, but it won't let me because the post is mostly code. OP, take that as a hint that you should provide more information. What I can say about the code is that you should use context managers, and I believe those loops can be refactored quite a bit.